# CMake cannot find libcurl-config.cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, libcurl, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to compile code with cmake. The code was imported from Windows onto a Raspberry Pi with Debian OS. The code works fine when compiling on Windows. Here is the error when I try to compile:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (FIND_PACKAGE):
  By not providing "Findlibcurl.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "libcurl", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "libcurl" with any
  of the following names:

    libcurlConfig.cmake
    libcurl-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "libcurl" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "libcurl_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "libcurl" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
```

Here is a list of the installed packages regarding libcurl:

```
ii  libcurl3:armhf 7.26.0-1+whe armhf        easy-to-use client-side URL trans
ii  libcurl3-gnutl 7.26.0-1+whe armhf        easy-to-use client-side URL trans
ii  libcurl4-opens 7.26.0-1+whe armhf        development files and documentati
```

Could this mean the packages are installed incorrectly or I have the wrong one?

Answer (score 0):

I did not touched arduino yet, but if you can access arduino's debian - try to do something like:

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl-dev --reinstall
```

and then:

```
make clean
make
```

P.S. You may have libcurl but CMake requires dev-information of it too.

Comment: You can't see it, but I have libcurl4-openssl-dev installed. What I found out was that the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH is at /usr/local/include, while libcurl is in /usr/include. How can I include this path in the cmake compile?

Comment: Try to add cmake option `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/include` or execute the following string in shell: `export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=$CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH;/usr/local/include`.